# Assign sounds to system events like Windows

Tags: events

Can sound files be assigned to system events in Ubuntu 12.04? In Win, I could play .wav files at startup, shutdown, new mail, exclamation, etc. 
I read somewhere about Ubuntu-Tweak & installed, it, without realizing it only works with Gnome desktop. Is there a similar program for Unity desktop? There are similar questions posted here, but they are unanswered

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can find is to replace the sounds in this folder
/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo
with other sound files with the same name.

Comment: I tried this, but Terminal will not allow me to rename the original sound files. The error message I get is:  chunkydrew@ubuntu:/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo$ sudo rename desktop-logout.ogg desktop-lougout.hld
[sudo] password for chunkydrew: 
Bareword "desktop" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 1) line 1.
Bareword "logout" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 1) line 1.
Bareword "ogg" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 1) line 1.
chunkydrew@ubuntu:/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo$

Comment: I have no idea what "strict subs" is

Comment: I did some research and found the 'mv' works better than 'rename' in Nautilus. Using that, I was able to change my login & logout sounds.

Answer (score 0):

No, not yet. Compiz, the default does not supports sounds the same way windows does. There is currently no UI available by default either.

However, there is one if the works. You can tinker if you wish. A good starting point might be [this site](http://www.itworld.com/software/286705/change-default-sound-theme-ubuntu-studio-ubuntu-1204).